# Controls to Auto Resize based on screen size

Tags: vb.net

All controls on my form, I want it to auto resize if the screen size changes as well.

I have different controls like the TextBox, Button, Label, CrystalReportViewer. I want all the controls to be able to auto resize when the screen is adjusted without them shrinking out.

Comment: This is not enough information for anyone to help you. What have you tried and where are you stuck? Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you're unsure why this isn't a good question. However, to help you on your way with your problem: a good place to start looking is the Form.SizeChanged Event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each control on your form has `anchor` in it's properties, you have to use that so whenever the user resizes the form it gets resizes too. You can also dock your controls to top, bottom, left and right.

Comment: I don't mean to personally attack you, but I find this a lazy answer. the anchor property by itself does nothing to resize the control, it simply sets the point from which the position of the control in it's parent get's defined. Dock does resize the control, but is limited to the specific scenario where you want it bound to a certain edge in it's entirety. IMO there's simply not enough information provided in the question to help this person at all.

Comment: Really? And if you anchor left +right and resize the form don't you see it get resized accordingly?

Comment: You are completely right. I was unaware the `Anchor` Property could be set to more than a single corner of a control. So in addition to my apologies i owe you my thanks for showing me something new.